# How to configure adds ADDS without DNS service integrated?

Tags: domain-name-system, windows

I'm trying to configure AD without DNS integration. First, I created DNS server and then tried to configure AD with that DNS.

One server has DNS role and now I am trying to install ad on a different machine. If I want to use existing DNS machine for that AD how should I proceed? Is it even possible? I'm using Windows Server 2012 R2.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes this is possible and fully supported by Microsoft. You don't even need to use a Microsoft DNS server if you don't want to.  But it's generally considered an advanced configuration.

You haven't really provided enough detail in your question for people to help you though.  You said you tried to configure AD, but didn't indicate whether it succeeded or failed. I presume it failed. Otherwise, you wouldn't be asking a question here. But you should detail how it failed.

Proper DNS configuration is critical to Active Directory functionality. Usually, it is easiest if your domain controller is able to perform dynamic updates against your DNS server.  When the DC is being promoted it will try and create a bunch of records on your DNS server that the domain needs. If it can't do that, it can still "finish", but your domain won't really be functional until those records get created.  Technically, you can create them manually. But again, advanced configuration and definitely not recommended for new AD admins.

Another question is why are you choosing to separate your DNS from your domain controllers (particularly when it appears you still want to use Microsoft DNS servers)?.  The usual reason people run AD without integrated DNS is when their company has an existing central IPAM/DNS infrastructure.  And even then, a lot of places choose to still delegate the AD zones to AD integrated DNS servers.